# chkdsk won't work on secondary drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, chkdsk

I have a secondary drive in a USB caddy attached to my WinXP SP3 laptop.

Occasionally I will receive a system tray warning that the 2nd drive contains errors, and to run chkdsk.

The drive is NTFS, but when I run:

> chkdsk /f f:

it says can't run chkdsk on disk in RAW mode.

When I run it the second time, chkdsk starts working, then says: "An unspecified error occured".

The system log says:

> An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk1\D during a paging operation.
>
> The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is the usb chip in the caddy has issues, or the disk has issues, remove the drive from the caddy and attach it directly to a motherboard of a suitable PC, back up the data and run chkdsk again, then run a manufacturers diagnostic utility on that drive, it may be failing.